# Alternative to imagemagick for text image creation

Tags: linux, graphics, imagemagick, image-generation

I have built a photoshop like program that uses ImageMagick (command line on linux) to do most of it's backend processing.  Unfortunately, I am just not happy with ImageMagick's text options.

ImageMagick's Text Guru actually recommends using TeX for more advanced text generation, but unfortunately that does not offer the cool effects that I need.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#tex

Are there any better options out there for me?

Comment: First describe *'ImageMagick's text options I am not happy with'* as well as the *'cool effects that I need'* a bit more... my crystal ball is in the repair shop right now (and they told me they're not sure they can fix it), sorry...